# If $ y \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$, is $[0,1] \times [0,1]-y$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

$(a)$ If $ y \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$, then prove/disprove that $[0,1] \times [0,1]-\{y\}$ is connected.

$(b)$ Hence, prove that a continuous, onto mapping $f :[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$  can never be one-one

**Attempt:**

> For part $(a) :$

I have a graphical situation in my mind.  $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ represents a square in $\mathbb R^2$. Hence, even if we remove a single point from this square, we get an arc connected structure.

But, how do we write a formal proof?

> For part $(b)$ : Suppose $f$ is one-one and onto. Then $f^{-1}$ exists and is continuous.

Unfortunately, I don't have much idea on how to move forward. Please suggest me an approach.

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) You nearly have the proof. Given two points in  $X=[0,1]\times [0,1]-\{y\}$, say $p_1=(a,b)$ and $p_2=(c,d)$, how would you connect them with an arc $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$? Well, if the removed point $y$ does not lie on the line connecting the two points, then $\gamma (t)=tp_1+(1-t)p_2$ works. Otherwise, you'll need to adapt the path a bit.

b) If a continuous and bijective function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]\times [0,1]$ exists, then its restriction to $[0,1]-\{1/2\}$ would give you a continuous bijective function between the non-connected space $[0,1]-\{1/2\}$ and the connected space $X$ (for which $y$?). Why is that impossible?

Comment: because $[0,1]×[0,1]−\{f(1/2)\}$ is connected but $[0,1]-\{1/2\}$ is not. Am I correct?

Comment: basically yes, but you try to explain (i.e., find a theorem) that makes this manifestly impossible. Intuitively, you are correct, being (path) connected is something that is preserves under homeomorphisms (i.e., it is a topological invariant).

Comment: uhmm, if $f: S \rightarrow T$ is a continuous mapping ,then if $X \subseteq S$ is a connected subset, then $f(X) \subseteq T$ must be also connected.

Comment: But, why did we choose such a restriction $[0,1]-\{1/2\}?$ isn't the function defined for whole of $[0,1]$

Comment: I think we applied the restriction to see if the behavior of the function remains the same on the domain and range? Am I correct?

Comment: you consider the restriction since that gives you a counter example. The original unrestricted $f$ is a supposed homeomorphism between connected spaces. There is nothing a-priori wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

Note: it is easy to connect any two points in this set with a continuous path. This shows that the space is connected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am able to visualize this graphically but how do we write a formal proof?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should think about connectivity in this setting:

Definition: A topological space $X$ is called *path connected* (or *arc connected*) if, given any $a, b \in X$, 
there exists a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ such that $f(0) = a$, $f(1) = b$.

Lemma: $[0,1]$ is connected.

Proposition: If $X$ is path connected, then $X$ is connected.

Sketch of proof: Assume $X$ is path connected but that there exists a separation of $X$, i.e. there are nonempty open sets $U$, $V$ in $X$ such that $U \cap V = \varnothing$, $U \cup V = X$.  Pick $a \in U$, $b \in V$, and find a path $f$ from $a$ to $b$.  Consider
$f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ in $[0,1]$ and derive a contradiction of the lemma.

A warning: there do exist spaces that are connected but not path connected.  These tend to be rather pathological, though.

Comment: it would seem OP was asking about how to prove a particular space is (path) connected, not for the general proof that path-connectivity implies connectivity.

Comment: You may be right, but I thought it might be helpful to clarify (for the sake of other readers as well).